# Undeclared Identifier 'L' in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, macos

I'm developing an app for Mac OS, which includes a cross-platform lib in C++. There's a macro defined as follows:

```
#define MY_GET(DataType,DataName,PtrFunName,DefaultVaule) \
DataType Get##DataName() \
{ \
    DataType dataTem = (DefaultVaule);\
    if (NULL == p) \
    { \
        return dataTem; \
    } \
    p->Get##PtrFunName(CComBSTR(L#DataName),&dataTem); \
    return dataTem; \
}
```

When compiling, the compiler generates the following error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'L'
```

Which is expanded from macro 'MY_GET'. After searching for `CComBSTR(L`, I can find other usage of L"String". So why is the `L` expanded from my macro is undefined while other `L` are compiled successfully.

Is L"String" legal in Objective-C?

Comment: Mmm... multiline macros.   The source of much hairloss.  You can view the pre-processed output of the source via Xcode.  Do so and look at the problematic expansion of that awful macro.

Comment: Thanks so much. But it's just a header file. How can I view the pre-processed header file? The menu item under Product -> Generate Output is disabled for header files.

Comment: The error must be occurring in a compilation unit (a .c, .m. or other compilable file).  Select the file where the error occurs -- the file that was being compiled -- and Product -> Generate Preprocessed Output (or whatever it is called) should be enabled.

Comment: It occurs in a .h header file which defines a series of get functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems that you need the preprocessor "token concatenation" operator `##` here:

```
CComBSTR(L ## #DataName)
```

instead of

```
CComBSTR(L#DataName)
```

The following code in an Objective-C file compiles and produces the `wchar_t` string `L"abc"`:

```
#define LL(x) L ## #x
wchar_t *s = LL(abc); // expands to: L"abc"
```

I don't know if other compilers behave differently, but the Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler does not a allow a space between `L` and the string:

```
#define LL(x) L#x
wchar_t *s = LL(abc); // expands to: L "abc"
// error: use of undeclared identifier 'L'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it solved my problem. It's ported from windows app.